# How to check the precise version of a transitive dependency in .NETCore.App Framework

Tags: .net-core, transitive-dependency

I have an app built on .NetCore v6.0.15. It is pulling some dependencies with the framework. I want to check the version of these packages on my system and compare it with the version that is documented on the Internet.

I somehow feel that the version is getting overriden in my system and therefore want to check if the version packaged with the framework is same as it is present in my App.

For Example: It is pulling `System.Text.RegularExpressions` package into my filesystem. How can I check the version of this dependency in my project and compare it with version that is present on the Internet on their Github repo.?

The SDK is installed on my system, so there should be some way to check what all packages are pulled during the installation. I would like to know that.

Comment: Look in the Output window while debugging your app.  It shows DLL load notifications, revealing where the .dll came from.  For example, I see "'ConsoleApp1.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\6.0.9\System.Text.RegularExpressions.dll'."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `bin\<build-configuration>\<target-framework>` folder of your project e.g. `bin\debug\net6.0` might contain a `<project-name>.deps.json` file.

That `.deps.json` file shows info about both the direct and transitive dependency hierarchy, e.g. a small fragment:

```
"NETStandard.Library/1.6.1": {
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms": "5.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Win32.Primitives": "4.3.0",
    
    "System.Text.RegularExpressions": "4.3.1"
  }
}
```

It also contains info about the involved NuGet packages, e.g.:

```
"System.Text.RegularExpressions/4.3.1": {
  "type": "package",
  "serviceable": true,
  "sha512": "sha512-N0kNRrWe4+nXOWlpLT4LAY5brb8caNFlUuIRpraCVMDLYutKkol1aV079rQjLuSxKMJT2SpBQsYX9xbcTMmzwg==",
  "path": "system.text.regularexpressions/4.3.1",
  "hashPath": "system.text.regularexpressions.4.3.1.nupkg.sha512"
}
```